# Google Analytics Content Drill down by page level

Tags: google-analytics, pageviews

I have been asked to generate a report with the top 25 and bottom pages of the website (number of pageviews and unique pageviews only)..but excluding certain pages. The structure is topic/subtopic/sub-subtopic/sub-sub-subtopic,(goes down 3 of 4 levels for most pages) with 6 overall topics. I only want to report on the most granular level, be it 3, 4 or 5. Is there an efficient way to do this, that future proofs the site as more pages or subtopics get added over time? 
I have tried to do this manually getting the reports via content drill down and working in excel and it requires lots of macros, was hoping to be able to limit the data via GA.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tired creating a custom report that just looks at pageviews, unique pageviews, and uses page path level 3 and page path level 4 as your dimensions? You can then add a filter to get at whatever subtopic you'd like, and save the report.

[image]

Comment: Thank you . I have now looked again and I have a list of URLs I need to track- about 150 in total. They go like this; www.Mysite/folder1/topic1, www.Mysite/folder1/topic2...there are 4 folders in total I want to track (the site has several others) and several topics under each, some topics have also www.Mysite/folder1/topic1/subtopicA . I don't want to see the Mysite/Folder1 level; only the topics and subtopics under it. Happy to devote a view with a filter to this if it is easier, as I will need to report on it monthly.

Comment: The report I outlined should work perfectly for what you are after.